# Does Python Do Garbage Collection on these workers, and how can I check?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection, python-multithreading

I am using Python 3.3 from Anaconda:

```
Python 3.3.5 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun  4 2015, 15:22:11) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Suppose I have some Python worker threads. They use lots of memory. There are no references to them elsewhere in the code. When they finish, does Python automatically garbage collect them? Is there a way for me to check?

In the example below, I create 5 worker threads. They are not stored in variables. Will they be garbage collected when they finish?

```
import threading
import time

class Worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.var = 'A LARGE OBJECT'

    def run(self):

        for i in range(3):
            print('hello %i'%i)
            time.sleep(1)


for i in range(5):
    Worker().start()
```

Comment: You will need to define your Python version, and the exact interpreter to get something close to an answer

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, Python GC is pretty much lazy, and you can never rely on it having happened a specified time.

Comment: Eventually of course, a python version would be helpfuly yes (at least v2 or v3)  and at IMO when the main thread finishes: yes  ;-) ... or do youe mean "exactly" instantly after they are finished?

Comment: I don't think I need it to be instant. I want to run a script for 24 hours. During that time, it will make lots of worker threads to do work. When these workers have finished, I don't want them to stay in memory. After 24 hours the script will die and I will start another one.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: CPython (the reference interpreter) _cyclic_ garbage collection is async and "lazy", but the majority of the work is cleaning up non-cyclic references, and those are cleaned eagerly as soon as the final reference to an element is released. Most non-CPython interpreters use a lazier GC than CPython, but CPython is usually what people mean when they say "Python".

Comment: I think the general point is that garbage collection of workers is similar to everything else. It will happen eventually.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think it is important to point out that especially in things that have worker threads, one must be very careful not to have any "dangling" references to objects created by a different thread. It's the hidden state that usually leads to problems here, not the question when exactly GC happens on unreferenced objects. Another problem are intra-thread complex circular dependencies that never allow the reference count of objects to go below 1, even though the thread stopped.

Comment: I think there is a chance of these dangling references, which is why I'd like to find an explicit way to check if the threads are there or not. Is there a way to count the number of active Python threads in the current process? Or perhaps I need to monitor my memory usage?

Comment: @Ginger: See [`threading.active_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.active_count)

Comment: I believe you can use [`gc.collect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect) to manually activate garbage collection.